# ItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem() returns null?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm having a bit of weird behavior that I can't seem to work out. When I iterate through the items in my ItemsControl.ItemsSource property, I can't seem to get the container? I'm expecting to see a Button returned, but I only get null.

Any ideas?

```
<!-- MyWindow.xaml -->
    <Window 
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300" Foreground="White" Name="mainPanel">

        <ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControl_1" Margin="20">
        <!-- ItemsPanelTemplate -->
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="2" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <!-- ItemTemplate -->
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding Path=Prop_1}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

    </Window>
```

My code is not working. Return null

```
    public static void StartWindow()
            {

                // MyWindow
                System.Windows.Window win;
                // Load MyWindow
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\MyWindow.xaml", FileMode.Open))
                {
                    object obj = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(fs);
                    win = (System.Windows.Window)obj;
                }

                //This code set ItemsSource
                foreach (DependencyObject fe in FindLogicalChildren<DependencyObject>(win))
                {
                    ItemsControl itemscontrol = fe as ItemsControl;
                    if (fe is ItemsControl)
                    {
                        itemscontrol.ItemsSource = new List<My_Class>() { 
                            new My_Class("Button1"), 
                            new My_Class("Button2"), 
                            new My_Class("Button3") };

                    }
                }
         // This  code get ItemsSource<DependencyObject>
                foreach (DependencyObject fe in FindLogicalChildren<DependencyObject>(win))
                {

                    if (fe is ItemsControl)
                    {
                        ItemsControl itemsControl = fe as ItemsControl;
                        itemsControl.UpdateLayout();
                        for (int i = 0; i < itemsControl.Items.Count; i++)
                        {
                            DependencyObject c = (DependencyObject)itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
                            **//This code return NULL !!!**
                            if (c != null)
                                Display.MsgBox(c.GetType().Name);
                            else
                                Display.MsgBox("NULL");
                        }
                    }
                }
                win.ShowDialog();

            }


public class My_Class
{
    public string Prop_1 { get; set; }

    public My_Class(string prop1)
    {
        Prop_1 = prop1;
    }
}

            public static IEnumerable<T> FindLogicalChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
            {
                if (depObj != null)
                {
                    foreach (object rawChild in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(depObj))
                    {
                        if (rawChild is DependencyObject)
                        {
                            DependencyObject child = (DependencyObject)rawChild;
                            if (child is T)
                            {
                                yield return (T)child;
                            }

                            foreach (T childOfChild in FindLogicalChildren<T>(child))
                            {
                                yield return childOfChild;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

the window is loaded

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the window and the itemsControl is loaded **before** you try to access the items? Check the `itemsControl.IsLoaded` property and redesign your code if it's not loaded.

Answer (score 4):

The ContainerFromIndex method will return a ContentPresenter. You could get a reference to the Button like this:

```
ItemsControl itemsControl = ItemsControl_1;
for (int i = 0; i<itemsControl.Items.Count; i++)
{
    ContentPresenter cp = itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as ContentPresenter;
    if (cp != null && VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(cp) > 0)
    {
        Button button = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(cp, 0) as Button;
        //...
    }
}
```

**Edit:** You should also wait until the window has been loaded and the containers have actually been created before you trying to access them:

```
public static void StartWindow()
{
    // MyWindow
    System.Windows.Window win;
    // Load MyWindow
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\MyWindow.xaml", FileMode.Open))
    {
        object obj = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(fs);
        win = (System.Windows.Window)obj;
    }

    win.Loaded += (ss, ee) => 
    {
        //access the containers here...
    };

    win.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: `ContentPresenter` is a `DependencyObject`, so he might not get what he expects (`Button`), but it doesn't explain the `null` value.

Comment: I guess thats much better :)

Comment: win.Loaded += (ss, ee) =>Thanks, this solved my problem.

Comment: Great. Please remember to accept the answer and vote it up: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Comment: As a side note, if you access the items right after the collection has been updated, the visual elements might not have been loaded and you won't be able to access them.     itemsControl.UpdateLayout() 
   fixed this for me.